# batch- needs to get first element of file name and check part of property name existance

Tags: batch-file

I have two requirements to achieve those are as follows.

1) I have couple of .xml files in a folder.
The file names are like abc.bcd.efgh.dep-bui.xml,cdefgh.abc.efgh.dep-bui.xml,wxyzs.cdrf.cba.dep-bui.xml
 I got the file name like `abc.bcd.efgh.dep-bui.xml , cdefgh.abc.efgh.dep-bui.xml , wxyzs.cdrf.cba.dep-bui.xml` from the folder path by using the following piece of code

```
for /R %%K in (*.dep-bui.xml) do (
echo Enter the port number for the service %%~nK
```

i want to get the word from starting of the file name to the first occurrence of . (first element of file name) 
clearly it should be like  abc,cdefgh,wxyzs from the above file names.
please consider first element of the file name is not fixed length.
can you please help me out how to achieve?

2) 
There is a .properties file(with name=value pair)
i can read each and every line from that properties file.
actually there is a scenario like to use regular expression to check part of a property name existence.
If the property is there,we need to modify the value of that particular property without rewriting the file.
clearly,
There is a property `httpconnector_port_httpConnector_java=9090` in .properties file.
I want to check for the existance of httpconnector_port_*.

```
(Because httpconnector_port_ is constant and httpConnector_java varies from one project to other project.)
```

If it is existed i want to change the value of that property.(9090 in this case)

how can i achieve that?

could you please help me out?

Comment: Edit your post to show the lines from 2 of the actual files. 1 with the Java in it and one without.

Comment: `without rewriting the file` ??  You can't change a file without rewriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1 this should work.

```
@echo off
for /R %%a in (*.dep-bui.xml) do (
for /f "delims=." %%b in ("%%~nxa") do echo "%%b"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

suggestion with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) (Q2):

```
sed -i.bak "s/^\(httpconnector_port_httpConnector_java\)\W.*/\1=9090/" "%propertiesFile%"
```

[download sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: can't we edit only the value by batch script without rewriting the file?if no then can we achieve that by rewriting the file?